# Mounting submounts of an NFS mount on Fedora 21 vs CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, freebsd, fedora

I have a FreeBSD NFS server with a mount, say '/mnt', and some mount points within it, say '/mnt/Documents'. When I mount from CentOS 7, the submounts are mounted automatically:

```
# mount -t nfs4 -o soft,intr 10.0.0.1:/mnt nfs-test
# ls nfs-test/Documents
stuff
```

whereas on Fedora:

```
# mount -t nfs4 -o soft,intr 10.0.0.1:/mnt nfs-test
# ls nfs-test/Documents
ls: reading directory nfs-test/Documents: Input/output error
```

likewise, if I mount this submount separately, the mount succeeds but I get the same error when I try to read the directory.
If I try to mount the submount within the existing parent NFS mount:

```
mount.nfs4: /home/_/nfs-test/Documents is busy or already mounted
```

The fact that it works under CentOS leads me to believe there isn't a configuration issue on the server side, but I can provide details about that if necessary.

Please let me know whatever additional details are desired.

Thanks

Comment: You should check the logs on both the client and the NFS server.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any relevant logs on the server or client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reluctant to make this an answer since it turned out to be a silly error. Moreover, the original question of the difference of behavior between the two distributions could still up in the air to some extent. In any case, I had forgotten about the ZFS property I had set on the parent dataset:

```
router:/root# zfs get sharenfs parent
NAME  PROPERTY  VALUE 
parent  sharenfs  -alldirs -mapall admin -network 192.168.1.1 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

The CentOS client happened to be on 192.168.1.1/24, and the property is inherited by all the child datasets that I had trouble mounting. Expanding the mask to /16 fixed it.

Comment: You also forgot to tell us that it was ZFS. Knowing this might have gotten you an answer sooner. If you need to ask future questions, remember to [include every relevant detail](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632) about the environment.